# AngularJS with Salesforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

Need help in knowing how to use AngularJS in Salesforce Lightning and VisualForce pages?
I do know that it has to be used using static resource but need step by step details in using it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share ur understanding and the code/efforts which you have written will now. You need to be more specific about the question, on SO we dont provide answer for a questions whose scope are too broad. I hope you are getting my Point :)

Comment: I think SF does allow to use external library in SL ( it might work in dev environment but I heard some company got rejected when submitting app so you need to do a lot of research before you start ) unless you use iframe and it will be messy to do angular with VF pages. I left the company who was working with SF 2 years ago so things might be changed but I would recommend to go with SPA solution instead of VF page if you want to use AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when talking about AngularJS, I believe you are talking about the version 1.x, because the version 2.0, which is currently 6.0 needs to be used in a different way compared to the earlier version.

For Angular 1.x, I am listing down the steps here:

- The very first step is to download the latest version of AngularJS. You can get that here.
  https://angularjs.org/
- Zip the AngularJS file and create a Static Resource, so that you can reference it in your pages. In case, you want to know how to create a static resource in Salesforce, refer SF documentation.
  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm

(You also have an option of directly referencing the CDN file in your VF pages, however, it is recommended that you should go for Static resources.)

Now, to get AngularJS in action, you have to do something called as “bootstrapping” your app.

This can be done in 2 ways:

- Use “ng-app” directive. (NOTE:You can only have one ng-app directive in your HTML document. If more than one ng-app directive appears, the first appearance will be used.)
- And the second way is manual bootstrapping. You can refer to this blog to know more about it.
  http://blogs.quovantis.com/process-to-use-manual-bootstrapping-in-angularjs-with-examples/

You can use the following code to see manual bootstrapping in action.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR(<your-static-resource-name>,'angular.min.js')}">
<div id="demo" ng-controller="demoAngularController">
        {{testVar}}
</div>    
<script>
    var demoModule = angular.module('demo', []);
        demoModule.controller('demoAngularController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.testVar = 'Prem';
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("demo"),['demo']);
</script>
```

Make sure you replace the static resource name with actual name that you created in the system.

I have added a code snippet as well.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);


app.controller('demoAngularController',function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.testVar = 'Prem';
});    
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("demo"),['demo']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">


<div ng-controller='demoAngularController'>

    <h1>Hello, {{ testVar }}!</h1>
    
</div>
</div>
```

For Angular 2.0

In case, you want to learn the usage of Angular2.0 (or Angular6.0 as known currently), you may look at this tutuorial and let me know your feedback.

https://premjpal.wordpress.com/2018/09/06/getting-started-with-angular6-in-salesforce/

Happy coding!